# How to mark a question a duplicate of two questions?

Tags: discussion, support

**TL;DR**

I have seen questions marked as duplicate of two questions. Can I, as a low-rep user, do that by flagging?

**Some details**

Earlier I had asked the question [What do scriptures say about luck?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42488/21103)

User [Ram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4435/ram) gave beautiful explanation in comments yesterday and also gave links to two old questions:

- [Conflicting idea about Karma in Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29443/21103) and
- [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/21103)

I think these two questions answer my question. I flag my own questions too as duplicate if those are. But in this case there are two questions which answer my question.

How can I do so? Is it something only high-rep users can do?

Comment: One way is if two privileged users cast duplicated vote with different questions or you can custom flag your question for the moderator, mentioning the same.

Comment: Thank you @TheLittleNaruto I will custom flag it.

Comment: Great! Good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible if close voters do caste votes to close the question as duplicate pointing more than one questions as target. Another way is to add duplicate targets as mentioned at [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/260388)

What you can do as an author of question is

1. Caste close vote choosing any one of the two target questions
2. When close vote will be recorded, the system will show you a notice "You question may already have an answer..."; Click on ["That solved my problem"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtT34.png) button so that [community user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) will close the question immediately on behalf of you!
3. Raise a custom moderator flag asking to add another duplicate targets.

By the way, the question you have mentioned is now closed as duplicate of two posts you have mentioned in custom flag reason.